# keyup event is not working after dynamic generated tr element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add total for rows and columns on keyup events. 
keyup events and every looping is working perfectly fine for addition of rows and columns.

But keyup is not working after dynamically generated tr elements.

**Please check this js fiddle** :- http://jsfiddle.net/f6LSU/9/

My Test cases :-
1) If I enter values in input box it calculates rows and columns total.

2) If I add rows it will dynamically add rows but that rows is dynamically generated so it's keyup event is not firing.

3) If I again go to the first row which already available then secord rows calculation is works.

So, keyup event is not working after dynamic generated tr element. I'm trying with,

```
$('.txtfld').on('keyup',function(){
```

I have also tried with second parameters in on event but it doesn't work,

```
$('.txtfld').on('keyup','printer-row',function(){
```

Comment: You’re using the selector `'printer-row'`, so you have a `<printer-row>` element, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your page was dynamically creating elements with the class name do something you would bind the event to a parent which already exists, often "document"

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.txtfld', function(){
 // what you want to happen when keyup
 // occurs on elements that match '.txtfld'
});
```

Or you can use a parent DOM element, That always remain in your page load  Eg:

```
$('parent DOM element').on('keyup', '.txtfld', function(){
 // do something here
});
```

Comment: Better than accepted answer, just because you explain things.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '.txtfld',function(){});
```

Comment: Thank you bro. It works. I know that there is only normal thing which I'm missing. Thanks Again. cheers :)